# load sections one by one with jquery ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery

I have different PHP files. each file contains code for a section. when the user scrolls down and I want to add content from those files on the home page one by one. Right now it only loads, does not append them and includes all files at once.

How can I do that?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var contentLoaded = false;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == 1000 || $(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            // when user scrolls load the partials
            if (!contentLoaded) {
                // right its only one file
                $("#sectionsLeft").load('private/shared/public_partials.php');
                // I want to load multiple files one by one
                // first
                // second
                // and so on
                contentLoaded = true;
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to use AJAX and in your PHP files you need to encode in JSON your output. There are several examples on the internet. Check for AJAX

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will